# Can Kolmogorov spectrum be used to describe the plasma fluctuations in the atmosphere of neutron star?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, neutron-stars, turbulence

I am wondering that whether Kolmogorov spectrum, which describes the energy distribution in turbulence be used to describe the plasma fluctuation in the atmosphere of neutron star.

As I know, Kolmogorov spectrum has been used in solar physics to model the small scale fluctuations, and there is also research on the turbulence in the core of neutron star and used Kolmogorov spectrum.

However, I haven't found references concerning describing the fluctuation in the atomosphere of neutron star, can it use Kolmogorov spectrum or other methods?

Answer (score 1):

The "low frequency noise" seen in the x-ray light curves of accreting neutron stars and black holes is approximated by a pink noise spectrum, power proportional to $f^{-1}$. There doesn't seem to be any way to relate that to the $k^{-5/3}$ energy spectrum of Kolmogorov turbulence. So, there's some sort of scaleless stochastic process going on, but it's not the same as the Kolmogorov process.

As Mandelbrot pointed out in "Fractals: Form, Chance, and Dimension", scaleless stochastic processes are very common in the physical world. They are, however, resistant to reductionist "explanation", so they don't feature much in physics texts.

However, searching for "neutron star accretion flicker noise" yields many results.

Comment: Thank you. Could there be alternative interpretations for this scale-invariant stochastic process? Are there any references you could suggest?

Comment: Thank you. I will peruse the recommended references.